# Why does the DataTable.Rows.Count not change after deleting rows?

Tags: c#, datatable

In my project I need to delete all records from a DataTable, so I tried this code :

```
while (DataTable1.Rows.Count > 0)
    DataTable1.Rows[0].Delete();
```

but this is an infinite loop, it seems that after the `Delete()` statement the `Rows.Count` does not changes.

It appears the records are still there but marked for deletion.
So I change my count to this :

```
int count = DataTable1.Select("", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).Count();
```

So now I can change my loop like this

```
int count = DataTable1.Select("","",DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).Count();
while (count > 0)
{
    DataTable1.Rows[0].Delete(); // THIS IS WRONG NOW
    count = DataTable1.Select("","",DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).Count();
}
```

Now the count does counts down as expected, but now I have a problem with the `Rows[0].Delete()` statement.

It will delete the same row over and over again.

So my question is, how can I find the first row that is not deleted, and delete it ?
In other words, the line that is commented with // THIS IS WRONG NOW what can I use at that line ?

Or is there a better way to do this ?  I tried DataTable1.Clear() but that does not generates delete statements when doing `adapter.Update(DataTable1);`

Comment: If you want to remove the rows from the table use `DataTable1.Rows.RemoveAt(0)`. By using `DataRow.Delete` you are just setting the row's state to `Deleted` which is needed for `DataAdapters` that update the DataSet/DataTable/DataRow, the underlying `DeleteCommand` is called which will delete the row from the database(or whatever the source was).

Comment: @TimSchmelter The idea is to delete the records in DataTable1 and when I later call adapter.Update(DataTable1); it will then delete them from the database

Comment: The idea is good, does it work? If you want to mark all rows deleted, why dont you use a plain `foreach`-loop? `foreach(DataRow row in DataTable1.Rows) row.Delete();`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I just tested with the RemoveAt(0). The count went down as expected, but the adapter.Update(DataTable1) did not generate any delete statements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to mark all rows deleted, why dont you use a plain `foreach`-loop?

```
foreach(DataRow row in DataTable1.Rows) row.Delete();
```

`Delete` will mark this row as [`Deleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) which is important for DataAdapters, they will call their `DeleteCommand` to delete this row from the database. But it will not remove the row from the `DataTable` immediately. If you want to remove it from the table use `DataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(index)`.

Comment: This is working and so simple, feel stupid that I did not think of this myself